# How to select all columns and a custom column in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to select all columns and add a custom column like:

```
Db.Table.Select(s => new { s.*, Table = "vAPP" }).OrderBy(o => o.TenKPI)
```

instead of:

```
Db.Table.Select(s => new { s.ColumnA, s.ColumnB, s.ColumnC, Table = "vAPP" }).OrderBy(o => o.TenKPI)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a basic oop concept. Inherit

```
public partial class Table
{
    public int col1 { get; set; }
    public int col2 { get; set; }
}

public partial class TableExtended : Table
{
    public TableExtended(Table parent)
    {
        col1 = parent.col1;
        col2 = parent.col2;
    }

    public string anotherCol { get; set; }
}
```

Then Select like below

```
Db.Table.Select(s => new TableExtended (s) { anotherCol = "vAPP" }).OrderBy(o => o.TenKPI);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
Db.Table.Select(s => new { TableColumns = s, CustomColumn = "vAPP" }).OrderBy(o => o.TableColumns.TenKPI);
```